# How to send a list to dynamodb?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to send some data to my DynamoDB table, but one of my attributes (b) has a list as value in the attribute $list like this : ["a","b","c"]. 
But I have an error when I try to send this item.

```
$item = $marshaler->marshalJson('
{
    "a": "'.$string.'",
    "b": "'.$list.'"
}');
$params = [
    'TableName' => 'tableName',
    'Item' => $item
];
```

How can I have send a list to DynamoDB ?

Comment: Always mention _what_ errors you get, not only _that_ you are getting them.

Comment: This `"b": "'.$list.'"` makes little sense to begin with, when you force an array into a string context, that will result in the _word_ “Array” only - so the result here is the same, as if you had written `"b": "Array"` in your code directly.

Comment: You should not be assembling JSON “manually” in the first place. Populate the according data structure instead, and then use json_encode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet in NodeJs,
I think should be similar in PHP as well -

```
    let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    let util = require('util');

    let table = 'tablename';

    let params = {
        TableName: table,
        Item:{
            "stringField": "someStringPartitionKey",
            "arrayField": ["a", "b", "c"]
        }
    };
    console.log("addRoleToURLPermissions Params => ", params);

    let dynamoDb = util.promisify(connection.put).bind(connection);
    let response = await dynamoDb(params);
```

Try not to use keywords like `Item Items, item, items` as field names,
 as they may clash with the AWS DynamoDb reserved keywords